# How do I resolve the build site error in netlify

Tags: github, next.js, netlify

this is the Building Error, How to fix it:

```
$ npm run build
8:43:44 PM: > weather@0.1.0 build
8:43:44 PM: > next build
8:43:44 PM: ⚠ No build cache found. Please configure build caching for faster rebuilds. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-cache
8:43:44 PM:    Creating an optimized production build ...
8:43:44 PM:    Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
8:43:44 PM:    Using external babel configuration from /opt/build/repo/.babelrc
8:43:44 PM:  ⚠ It looks like there is a custom Babel configuration can be removed .
8:43:48 PM: Failed to compile.
8:43:48 PM: 
8:43:48 PM: ./app/components/City/City.jsx
8:43:48 PM: Module not found: Can"t resolve "framer-motion"
8:43:48 PM: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
8:43:48 PM: Import trace for requested module:
8:43:48 PM: ./app/page.js
8:43:48 PM: ./app/components/Nav/Nav.jsx
8:43:48 PM: Module not found: Can"t resolve "framer-motion"
8:43:48 PM: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
8:43:48 PM: Import trace for requested module:
8:43:48 PM: ./app/page.js
8:43:48 PM: ./app/components/Nav/Nav.jsx
8:43:48 PM: Module not found: Can"t resolve "react-toastify"
8:43:48 PM: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
8:43:48 PM: Import trace for requested module:
8:43:48 PM: ./app/page.js
8:43:48 PM: ./app/components/Nav/Nav.jsx
8:43:48 PM: Module not found: Can"t resolve "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css"
8:43:48 PM: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
8:43:48 PM: Import trace for requested module:
8:43:48 PM: ./app/page.js
8:43:48 PM: ./app/components/details/Forcast/Forcast.jsx
8:43:48 PM: Module not found: Can"t resolve "framer-motion"
8:43:48 PM: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
8:43:48 PM: Import trace for requested module:
8:43:48 PM: ./app/components/details/index.js
8:43:48 PM: ./app/page.js
8:43:48 PM: > Build failed because of webpack errors
8:43:48 PM:
```

I try to deploy website in netlify via github, and I have searched about this error, and I try to change the **CI = npm run build** and change environment variables to **CI = FALSE** but still this error

Comment: Try `npm install` first. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found